# logcat command line options not working?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I'm trying to save logcat output to a file when running automated tests on a CI server. It works so far, but it seems that the options -r and -n don't have any effect.

This is what I use:

```
adb logcat -v time -f /sdcard/logs/logcat.txt -r 1024 -n 10 ESP_TRACE:S
```

This results in the following files:

```
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r     1582 2014-07-07 14:31 logcat.txt
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r    16409 2014-07-07 14:31 logcat.txt.1
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r    16599 2014-07-07 14:31 logcat.txt.2
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r    16570 2014-07-07 14:31 logcat.txt.3
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r    16691 2014-07-07 14:31 logcat.txt.4
```

As you can see the file size of the rotated logs is still the 16k default. Similarly it seems that the -n option to set the number of rotated log files is also not applied (default is 4).

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Or is this broken?